# How to add two references column to create table migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I first create the initial game model which is not yet complete.

```
rails generate model game room:references p1turn:boolean secret:string wordsofar:string wrongtries:integer
```

I am now editing the migration file to add two references column or field. The table should have two columns p1 and p2 each will reference User model or class. In other words these columns will both point to User models or records. p1 stands for player 1 and p2 stands for player 2.

How should i edit the generated migration file, before running rake db:migrate, to achieve the above goal?

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.references :room, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :p1turn
      t.string :secret
      t.string :wordsofar
      t.integer :wrongtries
    end
  end
end
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: if you havent committed and run the migration its ok to edit it.

Comment: thanks but i need to know the extra lines to add in the migration file in order to add the two references that point to same table.

Comment: Adding two columns will not be a good idea, because u wont be able to find all the games for a user in one query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `Migration` file as below, adding two `integer columns player1 and player2`

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.references :room, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :p1turn
      t.string :secret
      t.string :wordsofar
      t.integer :wrongtries

      t.integer :player1
      t.integer :player2
    end
  end
end
```

The Game class can be like this,

**this belongs_to two players referencing the User class.**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player1, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :player2, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Now, the User class and the players relation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :primary_players, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key => "player1"
  has_many :secondary_players, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key => "player2"
end
```

Here I referenced `player1` as `primary_players` and `player2` as `secondary_players`.

Now, you can call as,

**`User.first.primary_players`**

**`User.first.secondary_players`**